# How to create a Remove Sub Domain IIS Redirect Rule?

Tags: iis, web-config

I am trying to create a re-direct rule that will remove the subdomain and go to the main domain.

So if I have a url:  http://somesubdomain.maindomain.com/somepage.aspx it should redirect to:  http://maindomain.com/somepage.aspx

It is currently giving a 404.  What is wrong with this re-write rule?

```
        <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Remove Sub Domain" stopProcessing="true">                   
                <match url="(http://|https://)?(www\.)?([^\.]+\.)(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="myaccount" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="my-account" negate="true" />
                </conditions>                   
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:4}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below url rewrite rule:

```
 <rule name="Remove Sub Domain" stopProcessing="true">                   
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)" />
            </conditions>                   
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:2}.{C:3}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

[image]